How to format postfix headers correctly?
I am trying to set my email FROM header field each time I send an email.
First I create a text file:
To: myemail@gmail.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii>
From: sender@domain.com
Subject: nothing special

Main body here

Some other info

bye

The I send it with sendmail using:
cat testMail.txt | ./sendmail -t myemail@gmail.com

The mail is successfully sent. However, it is then returned by google with the error message:
Your email has been blocked because the
    sender is unauthenticated. Gmail requires all senders to
    authenticate with either SPF or DKIM.    Authentication results: DKIM = did not pass SPF
    [localhost.localdomain] with ip: [my.ip] = did not pass 

Why is the domain localhost.localdomain being reported ? The returned mail has the correct From field in the email header, so why is it being sent with the incorrect domain name ?
Help here is greatly appreciated.

This is not about From header at all. It's about your DNS records. localhost.localdomain is probably HELO name your system sent, which means, it's greatly misconfigured (it should use some real DNS name, not this). See this answer, it explains which things must be set up and what should be in sync. Also, obviously, your system has no SPF and DKIM; set it up properly too, it's not optional nowadays.

You have to set up the hostname and DNS records.
There is a guide here: https://centminmod.com/getstarted.html
And discussion here: https://community.centminmod.com/threads/emails-localdomain.12205/
